# Нужно узнать, есть ли в классе, другой класс/ссылка

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Есть html:

```
<div class="serp-vips-item ">

<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="snippet-vertical item item_gallery js-catalog-item-enum item_in_transport " id="i844016503" data-type="1"> <meta itemprop="description" content="...">
  <div class="img-container">
   <a class="photo-wrapper js-item-link js-photo-wrapper large-picture" href="/ivanovo/avtomobili/audi_a4_2009_844016503" target="_blank" title="Объявление «Audi A4, 2009» 10 фотографий">
      <img src="https://41.img.avito.st/208x156/4462480541.jpg" srcset="https://41.img.avito.st/208x156/4462480541.jpg 1x, https://41.img.avito.st/image/1/QJD377a_7HmBSh5_-_4O5GBM6nNJjOiLRUzuf09K7nlDCg 1.5x" class="photo-count-show large-picture-img" alt="Audi A4, 2009, с пробегом, цена 650 000 руб.">
     <span class="photo-icons"><i class="i i-photo">10</i></span>
  </a>

<div class="favorites-add is-design-simple js-favorites-add" data-marker="favorites-add">
  <a class="favorites-add__link js-favorites-add-toggle" href="/favorites/add/844016503" data-event-config="{&quot;id&quot;:844016503,&quot;active&quot;:false,&quot;categorySlug&quot;:&quot;avtomobili&quot;,&quot;rootCategoryId&quot;:1,&quot;access&quot;:{&quot;favorite&quot;:true,&quot;compare&quot;:true},&quot;searchHash&quot;:&quot;3ubvuaghdgys0sgg0k4k0s8socs8cc&quot;,&quot;fromPage&quot;:&quot;catalog&quot;,&quot;fromBlock&quot;:&quot;vip&quot;}" title="Добавить в избранное и в сравнение">

 <i class="i js-favorites-add-icon i-favorites-big i-favorites_filled-blue" data-state="empty" data-root-category-id="1"> </i> <span class="favorites-add__label pseudo-link js-favorites-add-label">В избранное</span> </a>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="description">
    <div class="snippet-title-row">

<h3 class="snippet-title" data-marker="item-title" data-shape="default"> <a class="snippet-link" itemprop="url" href="/ivanovo/avtomobili/audi_a4_2009_844016503" target="_blank" title="Audi A4, 2009, с пробегом, цена 650 000 руб. - Автомобили в Иваново">
 Audi A4, 2009
 </a> </h3>  </div>
```

в serp-vips-item, нужно проверить, содержится ли ссылка, которая находится в snippet-title. Вопрос может и тупой, но я хочу сделать без цикла, тюк мне поступает из друговво цикла ссылка, и эту ссылку мне надо проверить, не содержиться ли она в классе serp-vips-item. 
Вот кусок кода:

```
 document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(allhtml));
            var all_web = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(x => x.ClassName != null && x.ClassName.Equals("snippet-link")).OfType<IHtmlAnchorElement>();

            foreach (var el_web in all_web)
            {
                if(document.QuerySelector("a").Where(x => x.ClassName != null && x.ClassName.Contains(el_web.ToString())))--эта часть подчеркивается, он намекает на то, что тут массу элементов он берет, а мне нужно не делая цикл.
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(el_web.Href);
}catch(){}}
```

РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
 var all_web = document.QuerySelectorAll("div").Where(x => x.ClassName != null && x.ClassName.Equals("item_table-wrapper"));
            foreach (var el_web in all_web)
            {
                var Link = el_web.QuerySelector<IHtmlAnchorElement>("a.snippet-link").Href;
                var Name = el_web.QuerySelector("a.snippet-link").TextContent;
}
```

Comment: Во первых это не классы. Во вторых вопрос не понятен, при чем тут цикл? Чего вы получаете "в другом цикле"? Что мешает получить нужных два элемента и проверить, есть ли ссылка через `Contains()`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ код поправил, я знаю что контейнсом это делать, но не понимаю, как без цикла сделать

Comment: А какой смысл получать **все** ссылке на странице, если вам нужна только одна определенная? Пишите например `.QuerySelector("a[class='snippet-link']")` и работайте с 1-м объектом напрямую.

Comment: Мне нужно брать все ссылки на странице, а те что в serp-vips-item, их нуужно обходить, и даже цикл сейчас попробовал, что-то не получилось. Если вы знаете решение, скиньте пожалуйста кодом